# Converting pulse into volt?

Tags: signal, frequency, pulse, waveform, pcm

I am working on the lab which is allowed to ask other people for hints.

Below picture is part that I don't understand.

[image]

In the image, program called "Audacity" is used to capture that waveform.

My question is, is there a way to convert each Y-axis values of each pulse in signal in audacity into volts? (since the description in the photo made an example with volts V)

For example, first pulse in first signal in the picture, I can assume that it spans from around -0.1 to +0.8 by just looking at it. How can I convert this value into volt, V?

Comment: Why didn't the answer which you accepted to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/314286/cant-understand-concept-range-of-the-pulse-waveform tell you what you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you want.  However, the text says the vertical span of the display is 4 volts.  Thus 1.0 on the vertical axis is 2 volts and -1.0 is -2 volts. Knowing that, you can convert any other y-axis value to volts (just multiply by 2). Thus a span of =0.1 to +0.8 represents a voltage span of -0.2 to 1.6 volts.